# There are no data in Stackdriver Trace with rails and stackdriver gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine

Developing rails application on `GKE`.

I installed stackdriver gem, however there are no logs in Stackdriver Trace....

In the application, I just added `gem "stackdriver"` to Gemfile and bundle install only.

When calling [`new`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-trace/lib/google/cloud/trace.rb#L236), project_id and credntials are set [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-trace/lib/google/cloud/trace.rb#L246).

Also, in [`call`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-trace/lib/google/cloud/trace/middleware.rb#L150), the [`send_trace`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-trace/lib/google/cloud/trace/middleware.rb#L214) method completed normally without any exceptions.

The application have been completed normally, but there is still no data at Stackdriver Trace..
Is there any probable cause? GKE settings?

[`trace.append`](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append) and [`cloud-platform`](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform) are included in oauthScopes of GKE's cluster.
Stackdriver Logging API and Stackdriver Trace API is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had some troubles integrating Stackdriver to my rails app. Apparently the gem is using `protobuf` to send `gRPC` calls to Stackdriver's API. and there was a bug/issue in the gRPC client implementation that was preventing any API request to be sent if the integration is done as a Rails middleware.

More details about this bug is found here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/pull/2064

I've fixed it and it's now released. You can use latest version and report if you still have issues/problems.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/stackdriver), you also need to do the following:

```
# In application.rb
require "stackdriver"
```

Comment: In this [document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/stackdriver), note  ```If you are running Ruby on Rails, the stackdriver gem will automatically install Railties that will instrument your application for basic diagnostics. In most applications, the gem will initialize itself, and you will not need to write any additional code.``` My app exists `Bundler.require` and actually `Google::Cloud::Trace` is called.